# Understanding how to use UISearchBar with Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I have an iPad app (Xcode 4.6, iOS 6.2, ARC and Storyboards).  I have a UITableView that contains prototype cells, with two labels (lName and lPhone). I have filled a NSArray with the results of the Core Data store.  I copied the code from a sample, and am lost!  I have two fields I am looking for: name and phone number.  I want to be able to search on either one.  I tried using the UISearchBar Controller, but the results span the entire window, which is not acceptable.  So, I'm trying to do this without the controller.  I want the search to filter the shown entries in the UITableView, which this bit of code is supposed to do.

When I do the  MR_findAll (MagicalRecord), I get all of the attributes in the Core Data store.  This is where I'm lost - how do I get the two attributes out of the array and into the NSMutableArray *allTableData*, or is it even necessary in this case?

This is my code, so far:

```
NSArray *allDataArray = [ClientInfo MR_findAll];

//  move objects from Core Data store to NSMutablearray
[allTableData addObjectsFromArray:allDataArray];

if(text.length == 0)  {
    isFiltered = FALSE;
}
else  {
    isFiltered = true;
    filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (ClientCell* client in allTableData)  {
        NSRange nameRange = [client.lName.text rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        NSRange phoneRange = [client.lPhone.text rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || phoneRange.location != NSNotFound)  {
            [filteredTableData addObject:client];
        }
    }
}
```

I also don't understand *how* the NSRange is going to match against the two fields I'm looking for.  I'm really confused here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rangeOfString` method returns an `NSRange` with a location that's **not** equal to NSNotFound when a given substring is found in the receiver string. What your code does is that it first checks the range of the search text in client.lName.text and client.lPhone.text. Next, the code adds the object to filteredTableData if either of the ranges exist.

As for adding only your two attributes to the filteredTableData, this is simply not needed, as you should access the already stored object to fetch these attributes.

Finally, I'd also recommend you have a look at the free Sensible TableView framework as it should help you perform these kind of searches automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Have to do some thing like this

Fetch the Data from coredata into an array which is pretty mandatory and you have lot of tutorials on that.

And then in the search bar delegate method do implement some thing like this. Which will start filtering your array so that you can see your desired results

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    NSArray *list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:artists];  
    if (searchBar.text && [searchBar.text length] > 0)
    {
        NSMutableArray *filterContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:list];
     //    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title LIKE %@",searchBar.text ];  
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[c] %@",searchBar.text ];
        [filterContacts filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
        artists = filterContacts;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self updateSearchString:searchBar.text];    
}
```